# Appending to a specific element of a 2D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have this list `arr` containing n empty list and another list `indices` with integers ranging from 0 to n-1

```
    n = 4
    e = []
    arr = [e]*(n)
    indices = [0,2,3,0,2,1,3]
```

What I want to do is to get each element `i` in `indices` and append some variable to the ith element of `arr`. Code is shown below

```
    var = 1
    for i in indices:
        arr[i].append(var)
```

I was expeting `arr` will have two elements on its first list, one on its second, etc. However when I print `arr`, I get the following

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the first block as follows:

```
n = 4
arr = [[] for i in range(n)]
indices = [0,2,3,0,2,1,3]
```

now everything is ok.

### More info

when you defined `arr` as `arr = [e]*(n)` every list inside arr was referring to the same place in the memory (i.e. `e`). so, changing one element inside `arr` would change all of the elements. but when you define arr as `arr = [[] for i in range(n)]` then the element would be independent.